# Edit form showing up blank when adding Multiline column in SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, list, sharepoint-foundation, power-automate

I have one list and when I am adding a **Multiple line of text** column in that list with **Append Changes to Existing Text** option selected as Yes, edit form stops loading and gives blank screen.

I have to use that column so that I can use update item action in an automated flow triggering on item modification.

[image]

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue, please create a new list with multiple lines column with Append Changes to Existing Text option to check if the issue still exsits.You could also clear the browser cache to compare the result.

Comment: @Julie_MSFT when i am creating that multiline field with tick marks selected for add in default content type and all content types option, that time it is not working. Working when i am not adding field in content types.